# bus error when trying to access character on a string in C

Tags: c, linux, unix, libc

I have used this line of code many times (update: when string was a parameter to the function!), however when I try to do it now I get a bus error (both with gcc and clang). I am reproducing the simplest possible code;

```
char *string = "this is a string";
char *p = string;
p++;
*p='x'; //this line will cause the Bus error
printf("string is %s\n",string);
```

Why am I unable to change the second character of the string using the p pointer?

Comment: gcc has the option `-Wwrite-strings` that will warn you about changing literal strings by making them `const char[]`. Be aware that the Standard says literal strings are `char []` ("`read only char []`" in fact, but not `const`) and making them `const` makes your compiler (more) non-conformant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are trying to modify read only memory (where that string literal is stored).  You can use a char array instead if you need to modify that memory.

```
char str[] = "This is a string";
str[0] = 'S'; /* works */
```

---

> I have used this line of code many times..

I sure hope not.  At best you would get a segfault (I say "at best" because attempting to modify readonly memory is unspecified behavior, in which case anything can happen, and a crash is the best thing that can happen).

When you declare a pointer to a string literal it points to read only memory in the data segment (look at the assembly output if you like).  Declaring your type as a char[] will copy that literal onto the function's stack, which will in turn allow it to be modified if needed.

Comment: +1. Attempting to modify a string literal is undefined behaviour. It might appear to work but of course, it isn't guaranteed to.

Comment: "At best you would get a segfault" - actually, that bit's not quite true. Undefined behaviour is undefined and sometime that means it works as expected :-) There are plenty of embedded chips with no memory protection. Not saying your _answer_ is wrong since the question is tagged linux (so +1 for that), just that one particular point isn't necessarily true in all cases.

Comment: @paxdiablo:  Hence the "At best" part =)

Comment: i.e., you'd be lucky to get a seg fault.

Comment: Actually, at best (i.e., the best possible outcome), it would work perfectly :-) Although I would actually call that a bad outcome myself since it would propagate bad habits.

Comment: I would consider that bad because you are now relying on unspecified behavior and you don't even know it(!).  So yeah, agreed =)

Comment: A segfault is the best-case result. Worst-case is it silently "working" and changing the value of a constant string elsewhere in the program which happens to have the same contents and thus share the same storage.

Comment: That line of code was used when string was a parameter to the function!(in the past). That's why it worked, silly me. Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: That would still be the same thing.  If you were passing a pointer to a function and the pointer pointed to readonly memory you are still invoking undefined behavior.